# Add DEM layer to Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, dem, geotiff-tiff

I want to add a digital elevation model (DEM) layer to my leaflet map and access the height data through javascript, i.e. I cannot use .png files or qgis2webplugin but rather .tif or some compressed webmaptile file.

Any efficient idea or plugin recommendation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to dump that tiff file (or whatever) into a `<canvas>` and read the values of whatever pixels you want. Be aware of [cross-origin issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images#Using_images_from_other_domains).

Do read:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas